# Display alert message pop up the to the user when user checked or unchecked the checkbox using angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Scenario 1: User has initially checked the value for "Automated" and updates the value to unchecked state
Display alert message pops up to the user if at least one of the following accordions is in the "Completed" state.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
HTML
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 filter-opn">
   <form #checkboxfilt="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onapplyfilter(checkboxfilt)">
    <div > 
       <div>
          <input  type="checkbox"   name="Success" value="1" ngModel selected  ><br>
          <label for="Success"> Success</label><br>
       </div>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox"   name="Pending" value="2" ngModel ><br>
           <label for="Pending"> Pending</label><br>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox"   name="Canceled" value="3" ngModel ><br>
          <label for="Canceled"> Canceled</label><br>
       </div>
                           
       <input type="submit" value="Apply">
        <br>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

TS

onapplyfilter(checkbox:NgForm){

if((checkbox.value.Success ==''|| checkbox.value.Success==false) 
        &&(checkbox.value.Pending ==''|| checkbox.value.Pending==false)
        &&(checkbox.value.Canceled ==''|| checkbox.value.Canceled==false))
        {
            alert('CheckBox is Empty');
        }
  }


}
```